# Zend_Framework config problem

Tags: php, zend-framework, config

I'am starting to learn Zend Framework , i set up my first project right and created my database and wrote the action indexAction in IndexController but when i try to see
the url http://localhost/zf-tutorial/public/ i get the following error :

> Uncaught exception 'Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception' with message 'Configuration array must have a key for 'username' for login credentials'                                                in /opt/lampp/htdocs/zf-tutorial/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php:292 Stack trace: #0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/zf-tutorial/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(183): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->_checkRequiredOptions(Array) #1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/zf-tutorial/library/Zend/Db.php(265): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->__construct(Array) #2 /opt/lampp/htdocs/zf-tutorial/library/Zend/Application/Resource/Db.php(142): Zend_Db::factory('PDO_MYSQL', Array) #3 /opt/lampp/htdocs/zf-tutorial/library/Zend/Application/Resource/Db.php(154): Zend_Application_Resource_Db->getDbAdapter() #4 /opt/lampp/htdocs/zf-tutorial/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php(680): Zend_Application_Resource_Db->init() #5 /opt/lampp/htdocs/zf-tutorial/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php(623): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->_executeResource('db') #6 /opt/lampp/htdocs/zf-tut in /opt/lampp/htdocs/zf-
>   tutorial/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php on line 292

I tried several solutions (modifying my config in application.ini) but it didnt work 
here is a snippet of my application.ini file

> [production]
>   phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 0
>   phpSettings.display_errors = 0
>   includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
>   bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
>   bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
>   appnamespace = "Application"
>   resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
>   resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 0
>   phpSettings.date.timezone = "Europe/France"
>   resources.db.adapter =  PDO_MYSQL
>   resources.db.params.host = localhost
>   resources.db.params.user = mona
>   resources.db.params.password = mona
>   resources.db.params.dbname = zf-tutorial
>   resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts/"
>   resources.view.doctype = "XHTML1_STRICT"

any ideas .

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line

```
resources.db.params.user = mona
```

should read

```
resources.db.params.username = mona
```

Comment: thanks,can't believe i spent all this time & didnt see that :)

Answer (score 0):

change `resources.db.params.user = mona` to `resources.db.params.username = mona`
in your `application.ini` file.

Zend can't find the attribute `username` for DB connection